# Need example about nodes in QAbstractItemModel for QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtreeview

Problem: I'm looking example about creating model ( based on `QAbstractItemModel` ) to `QTreeView`, but can't find **sane** codes. Qt examples are based on `QStandardModel`, which is not very useful and complex, [Internet examples](http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/using_qtreeview_with_qabstractitemmodel.htm) are based on python?! codes... Other information can't gave me the right directions to go. So, here is what I have:

- `std::map`

  typedef std::map< CompanyData, std::vector< ContractorData >, LessData< CompanyData > > Companies;

Here it's data example (*CompanyName* + *ContractorsNames*):

```
[Microsoft]*
   [Bill Gates]
   [Steve Balmer]
   [...]
[Apple]*
   [Steve Jobs - R.I.P.]
   [Wozniak]
[OtherStuff]*
...
```

*where* `*` means - expandable item (parent)

And all that I need it to create `QTreeView` with this data above!

Can any one help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you look at [the official Qt examples for Item View classes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/examples-itemviews.html)? If there's one thing you can't fault Qt for it is the quality of its docs.

Comment: Mat, you are trying to say, that this example ( URL - http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-simpletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html , see TreeModel::setupModelData() func ) are really good answer for my question? I think not... It's based on file reading, filling from that file... Yes, it's nice, Qt docs great, but I just what create tree from `std::map`. I know, that I have to create some *node* class, but how to combine it with class inherits from the `QAbstractItemModel` - I don't know... Hm, maybe you right, maybe I need to mess about with this example...

Comment: You won't find examples that do all you want out of the box. But they give you the basics of how you use the APIs. Read them, ideally coding them and compiling them to get a feel of how the stuff works. Once you've got that, you adapt it to your code. Just the question you're asking in that comment tells me you haven't spend enough time reading the samples, and the Model View framework docs.

Comment: Ok, I guess you are right. Thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as no posts was done here, I post here my own solution (also used text filtering):

```
void ContractorsFilter::onCustomFilterChanged( const QString& text )
{
     try
     {
          struct MatchFilter
          {
               // data
               QString        filter_;
               Companies&     filtered_recipients_;

               // methods
               MatchFilter( const QString& _filter, Companies& _recipients )
                    : filter_( _filter )
                    , filtered_recipients_( _recipients )
               {
                    filtered_recipients_.clear();
               }

               void operator()( const Companies::value_type& val ) const
               {
                    bool isFound = false;
                    std::vector< ContractorData >::const_iterator con_i( val.second.begin() ), con_e( val.second.end() );
                    for( ; con_i != con_e; ++con_i )
                    {
                         const QString contractorName = (*con_i).name;
                         if( contractorName.contains( filter_, Qt::CaseInsensitive ) )
                         {
                              filtered_recipients_[ val.first ].push_back( (*con_i) );
                              isFound = true;
                         }
                    }

                    const QString companyName = val.first.name;
                    if( companyName.contains( filter_, Qt::CaseInsensitive ) )
                    {
                         filtered_recipients_[ val.first ].push_back( ContractorData() );
                    }
               }
          };

          struct FillView
          {
               // data
               QFont     boldFont;
               QBrush    whiteBrush;

               QStandardItemModel* model_;

               // methods
               FillView( QStandardItemModel* model )
                    : model_( model )
               {
                    model_->clear();
               }

               void operator ()( const Companies::value_type& val ) const
               {
                    struct AppendContractors 
                    {
                         // data
                         QStandardItem* parent_;

                         // methods
                         AppendContractors( QStandardItem* _parent = 0 )
                              : parent_( _parent )
                         {}

                         bool isEmpty( const ContractorData& contractor ) const
                         {
                              return contractor.id.isEmpty();
                         }

                         void operator()( const std::vector< ContractorData >::value_type& contractor ) const
                         {
                              if( !isEmpty( contractor ) )
                              {
                                   QStandardItem *item = 0;

                                   QList< QStandardItem* > line;
                                   line << ( item = new QStandardItem( QIcon( ACCOUNT_ITEM_ICON ), contractor.name ) );
                                   item->setSizeHint( QSize( 0, 25 ) );

                                   parent_->appendRow( line );
                              }
                         }
                    };

                    QStandardItem *parentItem = model_->invisibleRootItem();

                    // добавляем новую компанию + контрагента
                    QList< QStandardItem* > line;
                    line << ( parentItem = new QStandardItem( QIcon( COMPANY_ITEM_ICON ), val.first.name ) );
                    parentItem->setSizeHint( QSize( 0, 25 ) );

                    model_->appendRow( line );

                    std::for_each( val.second.begin(), val.second.end(), AppendContractors( parentItem ) );
               }
          };

          // удаляем символ(ы), которые не фильтруются
          // формируется новая таблица, которая и будет использоваться моделью для отображения
          std::for_each( data_.begin(), data_.end(),
               MatchFilter( text, filter_data_ ) );

          // вывод отфильтрованных контрагентов
          std::for_each( filter_data_.begin(), filter_data_.end(),
               FillView( model_ ) );

          ui_.treeView->expandAll();
     }
     catch( const std::exception& e )
     {
          Core::errLog( "ContractorsFilter::onCustomFilterChanged", e.what() );
          throw;
     }
}
```

PS: type `Companies` is a

```
typedef std::map< CompanyData, ContractorsData, LessData< CompanyData > > Companies;
```

where `CompanyData`, `ContractorsData` are simple structures...

Have a nice day!